# Rotate sphere by clicking on link in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created a sphere and I have a set of link. I want to change the position of sphere or rotate the sphere by clicking any of the link. I have tried to search a lot but can't find any example similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of creating an HTML element and associate a JS function to its "onclick" event. Here's quick implementation on a basic scene, using a button (you can replace it with a link or whatever you like):

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Rotate Mesh On Button Clicked</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Rotate</button>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="OrbitControls.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scene.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 var container, camera, scene, renderer;
 var geometry, material, mesh;

 var cameraControls;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    // renderer

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xdbdbdb );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // scene

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // camera

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set( 3, 0.5, 40 );
    scene.add( camera ); 

    // controls
    cameraControls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

    // lights

    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );

    var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
    camera.add( light );

    // objects

    geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 5, 5, 5, 5 );

    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(  {color: 0x00aafa} );

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );



    scene.add( mesh );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function myFunction() {

    mesh.rotateX(90);
}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

    cameraControls.update();

}

function render() {

    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

As you can see when the button is clicked it calls "myFunction", which rotates the Mesh by 90°, pretty simple.

Comment: Friendly tip. It is not a good idea to write code for users -- especially if it is an assignment. They should show what they have tried first. Then help them.

Comment: Sure, I had a basic scene setup ready so I felt to publish the all thing to give him a better overview.